# How to Create a constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I just Created a simple layout.xml and I want To put in this layout a constraint-layout as to manage the views easily by drag and drop how can solve this issue

................................................................

this is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuRL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#bebdbd">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemNameShowOrder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/itemImage"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/showOrderqtyID"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#f9762f"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="82dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtQTYshowOrder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="0" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:text="TotalPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/itemNameShowOrder"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itemNameShowOrder"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tpID"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: srsly..use google: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

1. AS > tools > android > sdkManager > sdk tools > (enable) ContraintLayout for Android / Solver for Constraint Layout

2. update AS to v2.3 ... 

3. add dependency in app gradle compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'

done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio allows you to generate from you old structure new structure with ConstrainLayout.

Firstly, add dependency `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'`

Then follow to your xml layout. 
Open "Design" tab, then open context menu from your root element (right click) and choose "Convert to Constraint Layout" option.

[image]

I've added screenshot how do it.

Comment: Thanks this helps me alot

Answer (score 0):

At first add the dependency to your gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
```

then you can add it to your Layout.xml as below :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@drawable/border_bottom">

<!-- your view here -->


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: should I replace this ConstraintLayout  with the parent linear layout ot just put this above and make it as a parent layout?

Comment: you have to handle your view items inside constraint layout, it's very easy and felxible

Comment: there's any tutorial how can I use ConstraintLayout  as I don't know how to use this control :D

Comment: [here]  (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

Comment: Dev.7arooney ...*sigh...30 sec google: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html
 my keywords: "android constraintlayout", first hit

Comment: @JacksOnF1re it's take 3 sec